# Problem installing 10.04 on Dell e6410

Tags: nvidia, installation

I get a blank screen screen on installation of ubuntu 10.04 on my dell latitude e6410.
It has the Nvidia graphics card. I'm sure someone else has had same problem but I need an answer a newbie can follow, please.

Comment: It looks like that particular machine has been certified with 11.10 and 11.04, but not with 10.04. It might be just too new for Lucid. http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201001-5167

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to install Ubuntu 10.04 on the Latitude e6410 Nvidia model however it does require quite a bit of manipulation to get it working properly. The best suggestion for a newbie would probably be to install 11.10 (and in a few weeks update to 12.04 if you want to install a LTS version).

If your determined to install the 10.04 version then read the notes section of:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Laptop/Lucid/Reports/DellLatitudeE6410

The blank screen error should be solvable by following the instructions there:

> After boot from installer media select the nomodeset option (F6)
>
> After installation, hit SHIFT during boot to get grub screen
>
> Change 'quiet splash' to 'nosplash nomodeset' on line that starts with 'linux'
>
> crtl-x to continue booting
>
> After login, activate proprietary NVidia drivers (requires Internet access?)
>
> Edit /etc/default/grub: change to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='nosplash nomodeset'
>
> sudo update-grub